# short int literals in C

Tags: c

Why are there no short int literals in 'C'?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329163/how-to-write-an-unsigned-short-int-literal

Comment: I had looked at it before-handed. Thanks for the pointer though. 

It is mentioned that short int literals can't be declared. Why isn't mentioned.

I was wondering if there was some motivation for the designer of the language to not have it and if so wht it was.

Comment: @Abhijith, you should edit your question instead of commenting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have a short int literal in C since all integer expressions are evaluated as if the subexpressions were at least int in size.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively: Because they aren't needed!

Data types of various sizes are needed to fit well with underlying hardware and/or to economize on storage space, but literals are a compile-time construct that gets stored into appropriate data structures anyway.

It's different with `float` vs. `double` because the same number actually has different internal representation in those - more different, anyway, than just a few leading zeros.

Similarly, there's a difference between `char` and `short` even though they may be stored in the same bits: If the programmer is talking about character data, it will usually be more convenient for him to specify, say, `'A'` than `65`.

But a short `99` and an int `99` look the same to the programmer, are treated the same in the program... the wider-ranging type will easily do the work of both.

Comment: "it will usually be more convenient for him to specify, say, 'A' than 65". Although in C, character literals aren't actually `char`, they're `int` too. So 'A' is a good, portable way of expressing "the integer value of the character A in the base charset", but it doesn't interact with the type system in the way that the questioner presumably wants from a short literal.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking *original* language design, remember that C got most of its present shape on the PDP-11 CPU, which is 16 bit. So they had integers for arithmetic and characters for string storage. Pointers were basically the same as integers.

The language was very pragmatic and only later got a more formal and intricate syntax. So the answer is, it just happened to be that way. Much later we got 32 bit and 64 bit CPUs and the need to distinguish between integers of different lengths.

To this day I code almost all my C programs like as if there were no type other than char and integer. Oh, by the way, "char" in C can be either signed and unsigned according to the standard. This reflects that chars were meant for character storage (strings) and ints for arithmetic.

To clarify, (thank you semaj) the compiler can choose to treat a variable declared "char" as "unsigned char". This does not happen for an "int". An "int" is always signed, but with chars you can not be sure. You have to assume that a char can have either unsigned or signed arithmetics. This is a speed optimization to accommodate CPUs that work faster with either implementation. I.e. focus is placed on chars as storage containers, not as an arithmetic type. (It's name is also a give-away. It could have been called "short" or "small", but was called "char" for a reason.)

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me.  How does the fact that a char can be either signed or unsigned imply it was meant for character storage when an int can be signed or unsigned as well?