# Integer division in C with unsigned short

Tags: c, arrays, integer, division

I feel like the bloodiest beginner - Why does the following not work:

```
// declarations
unsigned short currentAddr= 0x0000;
unsigned short addr[20] = {1, 0};

// main 
addr[1] = (~currentAddr)/2+1;
printf("addr[1] wert: %hu\n", addr[1]); // equals 1, expecte 0x8000
addr[1] = ~currentAddr>>1;
printf("addr[1] wert: %hu\n", addr[1]); // equals 65535, expected 0x7FFF
```

In printf and also in my debugger's watchlist the value for addr[1] is not as expected. My aim is to have half the maximum of the variable, here 0x8000. 
Info: I am doing ~currentAddr to get the max. 0xFFFF in case short is in a different length on my embedded platform than here on my PC.

cheers, Stefan

Comment: Is your purpose to have only set the MSB of the variable?

Comment: So debug it. What do you expect `~currentAddr` to be? What actually is it? What about `~currentAddr/2`? What about that `+1`?

Comment: I think the problem here is that literal integers (like `2` and `1` in `(~currentAddr)/2+1` are treated as `int` values. As a result, `currentAddr` is being promoted to an `int` before the calculation is done. For some reason, [C doesn't support literal `unsigned short` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906917/short-int-literals-in-c).

Comment: The key is that `~currentAddr` evaluates to `~(int)currentaAddr` on machines where `int` is larger than `short`. Note that the result would be `0x8000` on a platform where `sizeof (int) == sizeof (short)` because then the expression would be evaluated as `unsigned`.

Comment: Simply insure unsigned division.  Use `addr[1] = (~currentAddr)/2u+1;`  (add u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
addr[1] = (~currentAddr)/2+1;
```

You expect `currentAddr` to `0xFFFF`, which is partially right. But, what you might have missed out is integer promotion rule, which makes it `0xFFFFFFFF` which is hexadecimal representation of `-1`.

Now, there is simple math:
`(~currentAddr)/2+1` is nothing but `0x01` or `1`, When you `~currentAddr>>1;` do this shift, it is again becoming `-1`.

From

> My aim is to have half the maximum of the variable, here `0x8000`

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is get the value which is equal to (Maximum value of Unsigned short)/2. If it is so, the proper way of doing it will be using `USHRT_MAX`. Of course, you'll need to include `limits.h` file in your source code.

---

**Update:**

Referring to your comments to David's answer, following changes works as expected. (You have tested, I haven't)

```
unsigned short c; 
c = ~currentAddr; 
unsigned short c_z = sizeof (c);
unsigned short ci; 
ci = (c >> 1) + 1; 
unsigned short ci_z = sizeof (ci); 
addr[1] = ci;
```

Now, why this isn't promoted to integer as opposed to previous case

```
c = ~currentAddr;
```

It is promoted, but it yields an expected result because, as chux explainned (which I couldn't have done) it is (temporarily) promoted to `int` during its operation, but resolved as (converted to) a `unsigned short` again when it is stored in memory allocated to `c`.

The C standard answers the question:

**From the C99 standard: 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.
>   In your case since both the LHS and RHS are of the same type, there is no need for any conversion.

Also, it says:

> The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion.

The same is specified by **C11 6.5.16.1/2:**

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

Try this yourself:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short c; 
    unsigned short currentAddr= 0x0000;
    c = ~currentAddr;

    printf("\n0x%x", c);
    printf("\n0x%x", (~currentAddr));

    return 0;
}
```

This should print:

```
0xffff
0xffffffff
```

Comment: Hey. Pls see my reply to David Bowling. I have a separate line doing `unsigned short c = ~currentAddr;` that works - I mean c remains short. Where is the difference?

Comment: "Now, why this isn't promoted to integer as opposed to previous case

`c = ~currentAddr;`" mis-leads.    `currentAddr` is still promoted to `int` on 32-bit machines before applying the `~`.  That operation results in an `int`.  The `int` value is then saved in `c`, yet then goes through a conversion to `unsigned short`.

Comment: @chux: Oh, honestly I didn't see that coming. Thanks for explaining. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @WedaPashi Thanks for the update - this was the jumping point. So I better expect C to do most operations in standard int. The assignment helps me to make it _the other_ datatype. Doing operations with the unexpected type may / will fail like I have proven in my initial post ^^ Thanks

Comment: @Stefatronik: Welcome! If we (David, chux and I) have answered your question then may be You should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 6):

### What went wrong

The integer promotions are performed on the operand of the unary `~`.

On many systems `int` is larger than `short`. On such systems, for `unsigned short currentAddr = 0`, the value of `currentAddr` is first promoted to `int` in the expression `~currentAddr`. Then `~currentAddr` evaluates to `-1` (assuming twos-complement representation).

On some systems `int` and `short` may be the same size (though `int` must be at least as large as `short`); here `currentAddr` would instead be promoted to `unsigned int` since an `int` cannot hold all values of an `unsigned` integer type of the same size. In such a case, `~currentAddr` would evaluate to `UINT_MAX`. For 16-bit `int` (`short` must be at least 16-bit, so here `int` and `short` would be the same size) the result of `~currentAddr` would be 65,535.

The OP's system must have `int` larger than `short`. In the case of `addr[1] = (~currentAddr)/2+1;` this becomes `addr[1] = (-1)/2+1;` which evaluates to `1`.

In the second case, `addr[1] = ~currentAddr>>1;` evaluates to `addr[1] = (-1)>>1;`. Here, the result of right-shifting a negative value is implementation-defined. In the present case, the result appears to be `INT_MAX`, which is converted to `unsigned short` in the assignment to `addr[1]`, which takes the value `USHRT_MAX` in the conversion. This value is 65,535 on OP's system.

### What to do about it

To obtain maximum and minimum values for standard integer types clearly and reliably, use the macros found in `limits.h` instead of attempting bit manipulations. This method will not disappoint:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short val;

    val = (USHRT_MAX / 2) + 1;
    printf("(USHRT_MAX / 2) + 1: %#hx\n", val);

    val = USHRT_MAX >> 1;
    printf("     USHRT_MAX >> 1: %#hx\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
(USHRT_MAX / 2) + 1: 0x8000
     USHRT_MAX >> 1: 0x7fff
```

Comment: Hello David, I tried following:
`unsigned short c;`
`c = ~currentAddr;`
`unsigned short c_z = sizeof (c);``
`unsigned short ci;`
`ci = (c >> 1)+1;`
`unsigned short ci_z = sizeof (ci);`
`addr[1] =ci; `
(btw. how do I make a \n in the comment?)
Now everything is fine. But if what you said is true, shouldn't I have an int in my second line?

Comment: I meant shouldn't c bekome an int in line 2...
Sorry I am having trouble with the comment feature and the formatting options...

Comment: Note: "`~currentAddr` evaluates to -1" is also implementation-defined - yet very commonly the result is -1 on 32-bit `int`.  On 16-bit `int/unsigned` (common in embedded world),  `~currentAddr` would be 65,535.

Comment: @DavidBowling On 16-bit `int/unsigned`, `unsigned short` promoted to `unsigned` where -1u is 65,535.  Detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47555535/2410359).

Comment: @Stefatronik -- not quite sure I follow you; with `unsigned short c;  c = ~currentAddr;`, `currentAddr` is promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int` in some cases). Then `~currentAddr` evaluates to `-1` for the `int` case. When the assignment is made to `unsigned short c` the value `-1` undergoes conversion to `unsigned short`, yielding `USHRT_MAX`.

Comment: Recommend we delete our paired comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
addr[1] = (~currentAddr)/2+1;
```

Let us break it down: `currentAddr` is an `unsigned short` involved in a computation so the value/type is first promoted to `int` or `unsigned`.  In C this is *integer promotion*.

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.  C11dr §6.3.1.1 2

---

When `USHRT_MAX <= INT_MAX`,  (e.g. 16 bit short int/unsigned, 32-bit int/unsigned), code is like below.  With `currentAddr == 0` and typical 2's complement behavior, ~0 --> -1 and `addr[1]` --> 1.

```
int tmp = currentAddr;
addr[1] = (~tmp)/2+1;
```

When `USHRT_MAX > INT_MAX`,  (e.g. 16 bit short int/unsigned, 16-bit int/unsigned), code is like below.  With `currentAddr == 0` and unsigned behavior, ~0 --> 0xFFFF and `addr[1]` --> 0x8000.

```
unsigned tmp = currentAddr;
addr[1] = (~tmp)/2+1;
```

---

> My aim is to have half the maximum of the variable

The *best* way to get the maximum of an `unsigned short` is to use `SHRT_MAX` and skip the `~` code.  It will work as expected regardless of `unsigned short, int, unsigned` range.  It also better documents code intent.

```
#include <limits.h>
addr[1] = USHRT_MAX/2+1;
```

Comment: @Stefatronik pre-C11, for user code to discern the maximum of a variable of _arbitrary  type_ is not possible with risking UB  unless 1) the type is known to be some unsigned type and max value is known to be >= `UINT_MAX`  or 2) the `sizeof(var) == 1`.  With C11, `_Generic` can be used to find the max of select types.

Answer (score 0):

Because the number 2 is int and int can hold unsigned short,so,the the actual operation is `addr[1] = (unsigned short)(((int)(~currentAddr)/2)+1)`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you included a workaround to the OP's problem.

Comment: You might add an explanation why this is a problem. It should work fine unless already `(~currentAddr)` has more bits than `unsigned short`, i.e. `currentAddr` is promoted before applying `~` operator.

Comment: Well,I tried in my VS, and found the result is actually decided by the type of value  X/2 (because 2 is int and int can hold unsinged short,so result is int ),so you can write like this addr[1] = (unsigned short)(~currentAddr)/2+1;

Comment: The problem is that already `~` causes promotion. If the division by 2 was the reason for promotion, it would be `((unsigned short)0xFFFF)/2`which promotes to `(int)0x0000FFFF/2` resulting to `0x00007FFF` as expected

Comment: Some things happened....As you see,(type)(~)/int,lets see the operator priority about this equation,'(~)'>'(type)'>'/'.this commnent refutes my answer and last comment......

Comment: `addr[1] = ((unsigned short)~currentAddr)/2+1; ` seems to work.
I wonder why I hadn't tried any cast before? So Gerhardh looks like you are right with you answer

Comment: @Stefatronik Avoid casting as in `((unsigned short)~currentAddr)/2+1;`.  This may "work" for this C code, yet casting in a computation is usually a sign of other problems and better fixes exist.

Comment: @chux Yes you're right- I implemented the WedaPashi's suggestion `addr[1] = USHRT_MAX/2+1;`...
Good discussion here thanks to all proposals, I learned a lot!