# Where could I find all the C++ decimal type indicator?

Tags: c++, keyword

Where could I find all the C++ decimal type indicator such as

```
long l = 0L;
```

I also know L U f d. Are there any others? Where can I find them all? How do I explicitly indicate an unsigned short?

Comment: For an `unsigned short` literal, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329163/how-to-write-an-unsigned-short-int-literal).

Comment: See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: @lubgr, Actually I want to gracefully solve this warning: map<string, unsigned short> m; m.insert(make_pair("", 0)); // possible lost of data. I just find 0ui16 in your given thread, it's good for me, thanks :)

Comment: @Zhang: Out of interest, why can't you use `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>` as the type? Otherwise you'll get a whole load of type conversions at the point of use.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I just maintain our old project. It actually is WORD -  a kind of type used in Windows API.

Comment: you should use `static_cast<WORD>(0)`. it's best to be accurate with these typedef'd types because sometimes there will be preprocessor conditions that switch the type. I don't think that happens for WORD but it's just good practice to static cast to the type imo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This indicator you refer to is called a *suffix*.

For integer types, there are two types of suffixes:

1. *unsigned-suffix* — the character `u` or the character `U`
2. *long-suffix* — the character `l` or the character `L` or the *long-long-suffix* — the character sequence `ll` or the character sequence `LL`.

For integer literals, you can combine these suffixes, such as `ul` or `ull` to achieve both "unsignednes" and "longness" in the same literal.

There are also suffixes for floating point types: one of `f`, `F`, `l`, or `L`

1. Without suffix a literal defines `double`
2. `f` or `F` defines `float`
3. `l` or `L` defines `long double`

There are also user-defined literals, for which you can introduce user-defined suffixes.

As for your second question about `unsigned short`: there is no explicit suffix for `short`, so you will have to use `static_cast` or C-style cast.

**Another** way to do it is to define a *user-defined literal operator* like this

```
unsigned short operator "" _ush(unsigned long long int a)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned short>(a);
}
```

And then use it to define literals like this: `unsigned short a = 123_ush;`

I've checked that it works using this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

unsigned short operator "" _ush(unsigned long long int a)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned short>(a);
}

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  bool equal = typeid(decltype(123_ush)) == typeid(unsigned short); // check that literal is indeed unsigned short
  std::cout << equal;
}
```

For more info on things mentioned in my answer, I would suggest checking out cppreference: [Integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), [Floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), [User-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: Great, I like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. There is no such thing as an `unsigned short` or `short` literal in C++.

You need to use a `static_cast`.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: how about [user defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Answer (score 1):

a short list is :

```
1.0 => double
1.0f => float
1 => int
1U => unsigned int
1L => long
1UL => unsigned long
1ULL => unsigned long long
1LL => long long
```

here is a good documentation for both *prefixes* and *suffixes*:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-literal-in-c-cpp-prefixes-suffixes/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full list of inbuilt literal affixes in [lex.literal](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal).

I would cite the full table but we don't have markdown support for this, so here is a list of suffixes:

---

Integer suffixes from [lex.icon/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.icon-2):

- (no suffix)
- `u` or `U`
- `l` or `L`
- Both `u` or `U` and `l` or `L`
- `ll` or `LL`
- Both `u` or `U` and `ll` or `LL`

Which exact type these denote depends on the magnitude of the literal value, but if you look into [table 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#tab:lex.type.integer.literal), you will find that there are no suffixes that will give you an `unsigned short` out of the box.

---

For completeness, here are the floating point suffixes from [lex.fcon](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#nt:floating-suffix):

- Any one of `f`,  `l`,  `F`,  `L`.

`f`/`F` indicate `float`, `l`/`L` indicate `long double`. No suffix means `double`.